# Seamlessly play multiple sprites one after another with the howler.js library

Tags: howler.js

You have written a great library, thank you.
I have a question regarding some of the specifics of using it.

First, I'll tell you a bit about the application I'm writing. It's a microservice that makes it easier for kids to learn school poems by heart.

The text of the poem itself is on the screen, each line has its own checkbox. By selecting a few lines you can start an audio reading of this fragment (the audio file is pre-loaded).

Is it possible to run sprites in a row without stopping? The thing is that some poems have music in the background. And if you run the sprites through the onend event, they are still played with a small pause. That obviously worsens the perception. I would like to be able to set something like

```
sound.play(['part1', 'part2', 'part3', 'part4'], loop: true);
```

And have non-stop playback on the output. Is this possible?